# Trying to use tf.constant as loss value results in gradient returning None's, better way to do it?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, gradient, loss-function

I am trying to make my own GAN for a simple game AI after some limited (but successful) experience using tf keras for image related functions with a more standard CNN. In making the switch to this new circumstance, I cant tell how to make the loss function work.

Because I am using the model many times to evaluate each gamestate, but only trying to calculate the gradient and update the weights after the game is concluded, it seems to me that I need to disconect these two points. It also makes sense to me that I could just use a constant value for the loss function, returning a small constant value for a win and a large constant value for a loss. This results in the tf gradient fucntion returning [None, None, None, None, None, None], though. Am I thinking of this all wrong and have to make a structural change, or is it just an issue with my implementation? An example of how the code might flow is below.

```
with tf.GradientTape() as aiTape:
    aiLoss = tf.constant([0.001]) # this part is cutting out a function call to the loss function, but the end result is the same

aiGrads = aiTape.gradient(aiLoss, ai.trainable_variables) # this results in aiGrads being the array of None's
```

Comment: If you take gradients of variables that are unrelated, you will get None. Gradient computations only make sense when the variables have some relation, it is a mathematical concept, not a programming one

Comment: @Dr.Snoopy that makes perfect sense now that you mention it... Duh. Any ideas on how I can implement this sort of thing with the setup that I have? Do I necessarily need to use the losses from each of the gamestates?